# Include many files of very similar names all with one command?

Tags: pdfpages, include

I have dozens of `pdf` with the same name except for a changing number at the very end, e.g. `xyz1.pdf`, `xyz2.pdf`, ... `xyz38.pdf`.
I know the command `\includepdf{}`, but writing it 38 times to include all files into my new file is quite cumbersome.

Is there some command that includes all `pdf` from 1 to 38?

Answer (score 6):

EDITED: I tried it to verify it works.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{ifthen,pdfpages}
\newcounter{countindex}
\newcommand\includemultipdf[2]{%
  \setcounter{countindex}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{countindex}<#2}{%
    \stepcounter{countindex}%
    \includepdf{#1\arabic{countindex}.pdf}%
  }
}
\begin{document} 
\includemultipdf{xyz}{38}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `ifthen` package is to load the `\whiledo{}`, right?

Comment: @Lucas Yes.  I have edited to make it a macro.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `\foreach` command of `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,38}{%
        \includepdf{xyz\x.pdf}%
    }
\end{document}
```

This way, you can also use arguments that are not numbers (e.g. `\foreach \x in {a,...,f}`), or couples of arguments (`\foreach \x/\y in {a/1,b/2,c/3,d/4,e/5,f/6}`) — see in §*83. Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement* in the [PGF Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) how "smart" the implicit `,...,` statement is.

Comment: of course, you can define `\newcommand\includemultipdf[2]{\foreach \x in {1,2,...,#2}{\includepdf{#1\x.pdf}}` and use `\includemultipdf{xyz}{38}` as in [Steven's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337499/64454). The only limitation is that you should have at least two PDF (which is a reasonable assumption if you're using this macro).

Answer (score 2):

There are several loop macros available.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\multiincludepdf}{O{}mm}
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #3 }
   {
    \includepdf[#1]{#2##1}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\multiincludepdf[<options for all files>]{xyz}{38}

\end{document}
```

The options can be omitted.

This will load `xyz1.pdf`, `xyz2.pdf` and so on until `xyz38.pdf`.